# get attribute value of parent element from iframe content

Tags: jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, iframe

Is there a way to get the value of attribute `data-media` if I'm running the script inside the `iframe`content?

Code looks like this:

```
<div id="myDiv">
    <iframe data-create-resource-url="http://my.domain.url" 
       data-media="Song" 
       frameborder="0" 
       height="41" 
       src="https://different.domain.url" width="366">
     </iframe>
</div>
```

I've tried a lot of ways already like `window.parent.document` or `top.document` or `window.parent` and other available solutions but doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well you dont really need to access the parent. As you are running the script inside iframe. iframe is currently the window for your script inside iframe. So accessing window element should give you the said `attr`. Try this (not tested):

```
alert($(window).attr('data-media'));
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! Unfortunately, the output is undefined.

Comment: I tested it now and it should work. Check out the fiddle link in the end. As you can see in the source code, on jsfiddle your code runs in an iframe with following attributes `<iframe name="result" frameborder="0" src="www.exampledomain.com"></iframe>`. So my code `alert($(window).attr('name'));` should alert `result` http://jsfiddle.net/DDcvN/

Comment: @Jehanzeb.Malik This only seems to work when getting the name attribute .. when I try it with data attributes, I just get undefined. Have you managed to successfully use it with data attributes, as in your original answer? If not, perhaps it should be edited...

Answer (score 3):

Did you tried this:

```
window.frameElement.getAttribute("data-media");
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Will try this one.

Comment: Got an error though: Cannot call method 'getAttribute' of null. I also used .attr() and got the same error.

Comment: $(window.frameElement).data('media'); worked for me.

Comment: This does not work when the domain of the iframe and the web page are different.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, add an ID or CLASS to your iframe element (such as `id='myframe'`)
You can then use jquery to access any of the attributes with:

```
var parent=window.parent.document.getElementById('#myframe');
```

Now simply get your attribute (not tested):

```
myAttr=$(parent).data("my-data-attribute") or
myAttr=$(parent).attr("myelement")
```