# How to programmatically add data attributes to iframe that are accessible by iframe content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I am creating iframe plugins to enable content from a web app to be embedded within 3rd party sites. Much like FB plugins, the 3rd party site inserts a div, and a JS function appends an iframe to the div.

Again like FB plugins, I want to be able to define data attributes on the parent div, and have these control content within the iframe. After Googling around, it appears that iframe content can access data attributes on the iframe. e.g.

```
# 3rd party site
<script src='my-script.js'></script> #see below 
<div id="embedded-div" data-my-attribute="HELLO WORLD"></div>

#within iframe content
alert( $(window).attr('data-my-attribute') );
```

Is this correct? 
And (the reason why I haven't answer this myself), what is the correct syntax to programmatically add data attributes to an iframe?

I am creating the iframe as follows

```
#my-script.js
window.onload = function() {
   var elm = document.getElementById('embedded-div');
   var src = "http://location/of/iframe/content";

   var iframe                   = document.createElement('iframe');
   iframe.src                   = src;

   # how to define data attribute on iframe?
   # I've unsuccessfully tried variations like the following 
   # iframe.data('my-attribute', $('#embedded-div').data('my-attribute') );
   # iframe.data.my-attribute = $('#embedded-div').data('my-attribute') ;

   elm.appendChild(iframe);
};
```

Or am I on the wrong track here?

Comment: if the iframe and main frame are in different domains, then, you can't

Comment: Thanks @JaromandaX. I wondered about this. Can you confirm then that the following answer is incorrect, given that the Q specifically indicates iframe src is a different domain. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15358799/get-attribute-value-of-parent-element-from-iframe-content#answer-15359155

Comment: have you tried? have you read all the comments?

Comment: yes, I have read the comments and am attempting to test the cross domain issue. But as mentioned above I am having trouble configuring the iframe. What is the correct way to set data attributes on an iframe via javascript? my-script.js and div#embedded-div are on the same page.

Comment: _"# how to define data attribute on iframe?"_ `iframe.dataset.myDataAttribute = 123`

Comment: i use vanilla JS ... `element.dataset.myAttribute` to read/write `data-my-attribute` - notice the camelCase

Comment: thanks! very useful. was getting my jquery and JS in a twist!!

Comment: and @JaromandaX you are correct, data attributes are not accessible cross domain. So what is the correct way to use data attributes to influence the content of an iframe? Append them as params to the iframe src? Or..?

Comment: `Append them as params to the iframe src` - that would work